# Propel 1.6 Inserting and updatin many-to-many relationships

Tags: propel

I have three tables

```
1 - Items
2 - Suppliers
3 - Item_Suppliers
```

Third is crossref table between items and supplier.

My question is how can I save and update item_supplier table with propel.

On items page customer can select multiple suppliers  and than it will be sent to be saved in db. Is there any way to save it into DB with default Propel 1.6 functions. This is how data is coming from user interface.

```
array:8 [
  "Name" => "Strawberry"
  "CategoryId" => "2"
  "suppliers" => array:3 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
  ]
  "Points" => "20"
  "Description" => "Strawberry Description"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `isCrossRef="true"` attribute in the schema for your `Item_Suppliers` relationship:

```
<table name="Item_Suppliers" isCrossRef="true">
    <column name="ItemId" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <column name="SupplierId" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Item" onDelete="CASCADE" onUpdate="CASCADE">
        <reference local="ItemId" foreign="Id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="Supplier" onDelete="CASCADE" onUpdate="CASCADE">
        <reference local="SupplierId" foreign="Id"/>
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Then updating the related models is simple with the generated method:

```
$suppliers = SupplierQuery::create()->filterById( $input["supplier_ids"] )->find();
$item->setSuppliers( $suppliers )->save();
```